# Pretty, designer-friendly GUI library

Tags: c#, java, swing, user-interface, gtk

I'm figuring out which technology to use for my next project, and for now what's going to determine it will be mostly the GUI library. It's best if it has bindings for C# and Java.

It's going to be for a game level designer, and it would be great if there's a dark skin like [Unity](http://www.sutublog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/unity-3D.jpg)'s, or like latest [Adobe](http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/3340000/3340167/adobe-photoshop-02-700x464.jpg) products, or even like Blender or Sublime Text 2.

As for technical requirements, it would be great if it allowed Docking, though I could probably hard-code some part of it if it doesn't.
I already looked a lot for java Swing look and feels, or GTK#, but I couldn't find anything that's really visually interesting.

Is there any library / theme like this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of GTK+ has a improved theme support through CSS files. It's much more flexible than ever before. There is an [introduction](http://gnomejournal.org/article/107/styling-gtk-with-css) on The GNOME Journal.

More, Java and Mono all have [GObject Introspection](https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/Users). This means you could get a lot of bindings out of box if libraries support GObject Introspection. And it's exactly the **best**.

In fact, Unity, Blender and even Sublime Text are all written in GTK+! Just give it a go, and feel it!

Comment: This is awesome!! Exactly what I'd need to pass to our designers! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a lot with Java Swing. An example is [blueMarine](http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/bluemarine/), a photo management app written with the NetBeans platform (which uses Swing). (I'm not sure if blueMarine is still available - the [website](http://bluemarine.tidalwave.it/) doesn't seem to work).

See for example the book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But blueMarine still doesn't feel right for me, in the visual side. It will be a product for designers, and for us the visual aspect is very important. I feel a little shocked to know about the quality of the gui libraries for the most used platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I found a good one, https://vaadin.com/ (with a black theme, http://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme )
It doesn't support docking elements, though, but in the plus side it supports GWT and JS output!

Still looking for better alternatives, though!